# Do template functions always generate new code per type?

Tags: c++

This question has bugged me for awhile, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

This is mostly for quality of life improvements while coding, as I'm trying to get a pointer to a specific structure from an encapsulating structure. For this purpose, I just want to cast the pointer I'm retrieving to the one I specify in the template, and that's the only thing the type is used for, as I'm using other methods of finding the structure I want.

For all intents and purposes, this is the code I'm using:

```cpp
template<typename T> 
T* ExtractType() {
    // Get Pointer To The Wanted Structure
    void* sol = foo();
    // Return the pointer, not as a void pointer but as the specified type pointer
    // I know I don't need to explicitly convert void* to T* but do for clarity of the example
    return (T*)sol;
}
```

Will this template generate a new function for every type I use?  Or will it be smart about it and just have one instance?  The type has no impact on the operations of the function.

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 for this project.

Comment: I think this comes down to how the compiler decides to optimize code. You will just have to look at your compiler's actual codegen to see what it really generates. On a side note: your claim that "*I know I don't need to explicitly convert void\* to T\**" is wrong, because an explicit cast is required. C can implicitly cast a `void*` to a `T*`, but C++ cannot (the other way works though, C++ can implicitly convert a `T*` to a `void*`).

Comment: That depends on 1. whether the function is inlined, 2. whether the address of the function is ever taken, and 3. whether your compiler is being standards-compliant.

Comment: Notably, some compilers perform assembly-level deduplication which violates the "unique address" rule in the standard.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah, got a bit confused, used c++ for years, and now in school they are teaching us C.